# Target blank with Response.Write doesn´t work

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a linkbutton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtShowCompany" runat="server" 
     OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_blank';" Text="" visible="false"   
     CommandName="Show" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdCompany") %>'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And code the code behind is:

```
 Protected Sub lbtShowCompany_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbtShowCompany.Click
    Response.Redirect("~/company.aspx?id=" + ddlIdCompany.SelectedValue.ToString)       
 End Sub
```

I want to open the link in a new page, and I tried a lot of codes, like this:

```
response.write("<script>");
response.write("window.open('page.html','_blank')");
response.write("</script>");
```

or this:

```
OnClientClick="aspnetForm.target ='_self';"
```

**But all of this doesn´t work with my code, is there any other way?**

Comment: `Response.Redirect("~/company.aspx?cid="+ddlIdCompany.SelectedValue.ToString);` is correct syntax for redirecting with querystring.

Comment: Yes, but doesn´t open the link in a new page, it´s open in the same page, and I don´t like this.

Comment: @CodV092 - Same Page cz you have use `self`, you should use `blank` instead.

Comment: this line `Response.Redirect("~/company.aspx=" + ddlIdCompany.SelectedValue.ToString) `  doesn't make sense.Are you trying to pass query string?

Comment: Sorry I write it wrong in the description, because I put dummy data from my code, but in my real code I put the URL correctly, but that is not the problem, I suspect that there are something in the browser that blocked to open the page, but I don´t know.

Comment: Modern browsers typically block the `window.open` method unless it is directly called from within an onclick event handler in JavaScript. The simplest solution would probably be to replace the `<asp:LinkButton CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdCompany") %>' ...` with `<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("IdCompany", "~/company.aspx?id={0}") %>' Target="_blank" ...`

Comment: I put the same thing you write and when I execute the code is´t give a Compilation error message.

Comment: Sorry, the ellipses (the three dots ... ) indicate that there is some implied information not shown. In this case, the rest of the ASP tag content like "runat='server'", the ID attribute, the Visible attribute, etc.  Since I didn't know how you were using the link button specifically (e.g. I can't see where you are getting the text for the link itself), I didn't want to put in complete code, just make a general suggestion about using `asp:HyperLink` instead of `asp:LinkButton`

Comment: I put this code but doesn´t work:                                           '<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Idompany", "~/company.aspx?id={0}") %>' ID="lbtShowCompany" Target="_blank"  runat="server"></asp:HyperLink> '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlShowCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IdCompany") %>' Target="_blank" 
NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/company.aspx?Id={0}",Eval("IdCompany")) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

I wish this can help you.